# Is there any way to make a base spring-boot component which shared with several different components?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm looking for a solution to make a common-spring-boot component to avoid the many duplicate files
in several different components. i.e:
There are 2 components(say, C1 and C2) built based on the spring-boot to provide the RESTful services, the swagger is used in both of them to show the generated API docs, and the generated fat jar looks like:

```
C1.jar
│  logback-access.xml
│  logback.xml
├─com.host.c1.*
├─db
├─lib
├─logging
│      logback-access-base.xml
│      logback-base.xml
├─META-INF
├─org. springframework.boot.loader
└─static
    └─swagger.ui.app
```

C2.jar is almost the same with C1.jar, but the different package name (com.**host.c2.***).

We can see that there are many duplicate file in these 2 components, I'd like to make a common component to include all the common resources and configurations files to keep the component structure clean, say:

```
 BaseComponent.jar 
 │  logback-access.xml
 │  logback.xml
 ├─com.host.base.*
 ├─lib
 ├─logging
 │      logback-access-base.xml
 │      logback-base.xml
 ├─META-INF
 ├─org. springframework.boot.loader
 └─static
     └─swagger.ui.app
```

In this way, the new C1 and C2 based on the BaseComponent would look like:

```
 C1.jar
 ├─com.host.c1.*
 ├─lib ... BaseComponent.jar

 C2.jar
 ├─com.host.c1.*
 ├─lib ... BaseComponent.jar
```

I tried this manually but it did not work ,but the following excepiton when run the modified jar:

```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to open nested compressed entry lib/BaseComponent.jar
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFileFromFileEntry(JarFile.java:342)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:312)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchive(JarFileArchive.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchives(JarFileArchive.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.getClassPathArchives(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:56)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:45)
```

Is it possible to achieve it?
Any suggestion/solution would be appreciated.

Comment: "Unable to open nested compressed entry". Should give you a clue. How did you build the jar files (the nested one and the outer one)? If you use standard build tools like Maven and Gradle this tends not to happen.

Comment: I built the jar files with maven first then I removed the unnecessary files from it via WinRAR, to make a common jar manually to test it.

Comment: WinRAR is probably the culprit then. You can build a jar with nested lib dir using spring-boot maven plugin, so I suggest you do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Creating an executable jar

Spring Boot requires nested entries to be [stored without any compression](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.1.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-loader/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFile.java#L339-L347). The problem is that you've built the jar manually and, as a result, have compressed the nested jar file. Spring Boot's Maven and Gradle plugins will take care of this for you. Alternatively, if you want to continue to build the jar by hand, it should be possible to disable compression but it'll depend on the tool you're using. For example if you're using `zip` on OS X `-Zstore` will make it store the entries with no compression.

As an aside, the methods shown in your stack trace only exist in older versions of Spring Boot (1.1.1 is the latest version that has them). It's unrelated to this issue, but I'd recommend upgrading to 1.1.7.

#### Component scanning and loading configuration from nested jars

When a Spring Boot app is performing component scanning, trying to load configuration files, etc it will use the classpath to do so, i.e. it doesn't matter if the files and classes are in the main jar file or one of the nested jar files as they're all on the classpath. As long as you follow the same approach for any resource loading that you do in your own code (use `classpath:/` prefixed resource locations) you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation for the Component scanning and the configuration loading, it's clear for me. I think it should work well via the following steps:  

1. Build my BaseComponent as a general jar file by using the maven-jar plugin instead of Spring Boot's Maven plugins.  
2. Add the dependency of BaseComponent into the poms of C1 and C2   <br/>3. Build C1 and C2 with Spring Boot's Maven plugins and let BaseComponent.jar can be included into 'lib'   <br/>It should work well,right? I'll let you know the result after it checked.

Comment: Why BreakLines can NOT be added even 2 spaces added in the end of the line in the comment? The help says: 'Linebreaks: End a line with two spaces to add a <br/> linebreak'

Comment: @Anndy Thanks, it works when the jars generated via the specific maven-plugins after the POMs modified accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Andy,
Yes, I know Spring Boot's Maven plugin can take care of it. I just want to check if it works in this way. I'd like to know if Spring Boot can do the following things from a nested jar file well:

1. Loading the log configurations
2. Scanning and initiating the Annotated Components,Controllers,Interceptors,and etc

BTW,
You are right, the used Spring Boot is 1.0.2.RELEASE, it's old, I'll upgrade it later.

Comment: I think this would have been better posted as a comment as it's not an answer to your question. I've updated my answer to cover this part of your question as well